# Operation has timed out error on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, smtp

I'm getting an error while sending email through asp.net SMTP server. It says operation has timed out. How to overcome the exception?

```
   try
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();

        mail.From = new MailAddress("mymailid@hotmail.com");
        mail.To.Add("yourmailid@gmail.com");
        mail.Subject = "Verify your account";
        mail.Body = "Your OTP for your account verification is "+OTP.ToString()+". Enter your OTP in verification window.";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        SmtpServer.Timeout = 20000;
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        errmsgShow.Text = "Mail sent";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //string errMsg = "alert('OTP sending failed. Error: " +e.ToString()+ "')";
        //ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "ClientScript", errMsg, true);
        //Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
        errmsgShow.Text = e.ToString();
    }
```

I have also included below in the web.config

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
    <network host="smtp.live.com" port="25" userName="mymailid@hotmail.com" password="password" enableSsl="true"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `SmtpServer.Timeout = 20000;`.

Update:

i see you have `SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();`.

SmtpServer is a property of SmtpMail `SmtpMail.SmtpServer`. Try changing the variable name, something like

```
SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient();
```

Comment: changed the SmtpClient object name. But still the error remains same.